# WebView load on android 5.0 sometimes cause app stuck and crash

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-5.0-lollipop

I use WebView to load urls and also send and receive Java script calls.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            if (newProgress == 100) {
                showContentOrLoadingIndicator(true);
            }
        }

    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
     }
```

The code works fine on android < 5 but on lollipop versions sometimes the app simply get totally stuck and sometimes crash.

Any idea why?

Comment: Got any logcat for us?

Comment: Just found this: http://www.droid-life.com/2015/04/27/apps-crashing-android-system-webview/ lookes like the fix work but why? and how to solve it programaticlly

Comment: Then only Google know (sadly)...